# Xcode - Simple app

Tags: ios, objective-c, while-loop

I've been using Xcode to create a very simple application that takes user input and compares the name that has been entered with some target name.  If they match, a special message is printed, and if not, a generic one is displayed.  I've almost got my preliminary thing working, which is what I wanted to do before I try and make an iOS app for it.  It goes something like this.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *targetName = @"Eris";

        char prelimName[100];
        NSString *name;

        int continue = 1;
        char continueString[100];

        while(continue == 1){

            NSLog(@"Type in your name.");
            scanf("%s", prelimName);

            //Convert to NSString
            name = [NSString stringWithCString: prelimName encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            if([name isEqualToString: targetName]){
                NSLog(@"Ay gurl, lemme holla atchu.");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Hi, %@.  Now I'm disappointed.", name);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get that bits and pieces are missing (mostly a way to terminate the loop) but I'm struggling to make this thing stop giving me errors.  I'm used to Java and other C languages and I don't get why I can't just have a loop controlled with a boolean condition like:

boolean continue = true;

```
while(continue){
...
}
```

Instead, I get an "expected expression" error either on the loop or wherever I try to define the boolean.  I've looked around and nothing is clear about how to use a simple boolean variable to control the loop.  I just started working with Objective C today and I'm already getting frustrated with the interface that I'm required to use for this assignment.  What sort of fix do I need to make?  Additionally, how would I convert the preliminary application to an iOS one?

Comment: Just use `while(true) {}`. You can get out of the loop to use `break;` at some point in your application (e.g. when a certain text is being entered). No need to use a separate variable.

Comment: `continue` is a reserved keyword (just as in Java and other [C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ceyyskb.aspx) languages)

Answer (score 1):

`continue` is a keyword in the C language (so also in Objective-C which is a superset):
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/continue

Simply name your variable differently...

About your iOS related question, please ask another question, with details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also booleans are defined as BOOL (all caps) and the values are YES and NO (instead of true and false).

Comment: That helped with my first situation and the thing is running now.  How can I go about converting this to an iOS application?  I'm aware that Xcode offers iOS app tools but I tried watching a video or two about it and none of it made sense.

Comment: @user3521737 This is just too broad to answer here... Try to find tutorials or books about iOS programming, and ask other questions here on SO when you have concrete questions.

Comment: @Murillo At this point, it's effectively a stylistic choice. `bool`, `true`, and `false` are a part of Obj-C as much as any other part of C99. Plenty of Apple's own frameworks use true and false (obviously the C-only ones, but also the Obj-C one's that interface with them). Another C99-ism is to-end-of-line comments with '//' -- do you really not use those? ;-) Personally, I still use YES and NO more frequently in my Obj-C code.

Comment: EDIT: Found the issue.  Xcode has an awful interface.

Comment: @user3521737 Your program is a command line tool... So no GUI... If you want to build a GUI app, then select the right project template from Xcode (Cocoa application instead of Command line tool). And learn from there...

Comment: @greymouser That's true. I just verified it and it worked well. Funny enough, I've been using BOOL, YES and NO for so long, I didn't even know that. Thanks, living and learning.